# Strange question about Taylor series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, recurrence-relations, taylor-expansion

I try to get a series expansion (not necessarily Taylor) or even an integral or any nice formula, for a special continuous function satisfying a peculiar, simple functional equation:

$f(x^a) = f(1+x) - f(1-x)$.

Here $a$ is a negative constant. Let $x_0$ be a solution of $x_0^a = 1+x_0$ or $x_0^a =1 - x_0$ and let $x_1 = x_0^a$ and $x_2 = 2-x_0$.

It is easy to obtain a simple relationship between the derivatives of $x$ taken at $x=x_1$ and $x=x_2$. While this is not enough to get a Taylor series around $x=x_1$ or $x=x_2$, is it enough to get a series expansion for $f$?

Note that if $x_0^a=1+x_0 = x_1$, we have:

$f(x_1)  = f(x_1) - f(x_2)\\
ax_0^{a-1} f'(x_1) = f'(x_1) - f'(x_2)\\
ax_0^{a-1}f''(x_1) + a(a-1)x_0^{a-2}f'(x_1) = f''(x_1) - f''(x_2).$

It is easy to iteratively differentiate the above expression, but does it lead to something interesting, in terms of a nice expression for the function $f$ -- an expression that allows you to easily tabulate $f$?

Comment: $f(x)\equiv0$ satisfies the equation, so I think you'd need some more information to get a series, if indeed there is another solution.

Comment: My function is related to the probability distribution satisfying $F_X(x) = 1 + F_X(1+x^{-1/b}) - F_X(1-x^{-1/b})$ with $x \geq 0$ and $b>0$. This distribution itself is the equilibrium distribution for the chaotic sequence $x(n+1) = |1-x(n)|^{-b}$ with (say) $x(0) = \sqrt{2}$, though other seeds (say $x(0) = \log 2$)  lead to the same equilibrium.

Comment: To be more specific, $F_X(x) = 1-f(x)$ and $b = -1/a$.The case $b = 1/2$ is of special interest.

Comment: Try assuming that $f(x) = \sum_n a_n(x -1)^n$ Use it to express the Taylor series (about $x = 1$) of $f(x^\alpha)$ and $f(1+ x) -f(1-x)$. ($x^\alpha$ has a singularity at $x = 0$, so you need its taylor series about something else). Use these to rewrite your functional equation into an equation on the coefficients $a_n$. See if this allows you to calculate what $a_n$ is.